# CSS: Position problem

Tags: html, css

Hey guys. Im setting a position:absolute to my UL to make it appear on the bottom of div #destaques, but isnt work. Whats going on?

```
<div id="destaques">
<ul>//stuff</ul>
<div class="banner"><img src="images/001.jpg"/></div>
<div class="banner"><img src="images/002.jpg"/></div>
<div class="banner"><img src="images/003.jpg"/></div>
<div class="banner"><img src="images/004.jpg"/></div>
</div>
```

Its currently appearing on the page bottom.

```
        #destaques {
            margin:0;
            padding:0;
            width:1000px;
            height:250px;
            float:left;
            overflow:hidden;
        }

        #destaques .banner {
            position:absolute;
        }

        #destaques ul {
            float:left;
            border:1px solid #777;
            background:#fff;
            position:absolute;
            margin:0;
            color:#333;
            padding:0;
            right:0px;
        }
```

What im doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: You should read up on CSS layout some more. There is absolutely no reason for giving `float` and `position: absolute` to the same element.

Comment: I found my answer. I just have to setup the destaques id to position: relative. Thanks to all.

Comment: `ul` can have only `li` childs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add:

```
position:relative;
```

to your #destaques div

Comment: Relative positioned containers will hold absolute positioned elements within it that are contained inside its tags.